# Spring 4 @Service with @RequestScope

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, service, scope

In order to optimize sql request, I've made a service that aggregate other services consumptions to avoid unecessary calls.
(Some pages of my webapp are called millions times by day, so I want to reuse the results of database queries as many times as possible on each request)

The solution I create is this one :

My service has @RequestScope instead of default scope (Singleton)

In MyService

```
@Service
@RequestScope
public MyService {

private int param;

@Autowired
private OtherService otherService;

@Autowired
private OtherService2 otherService2;

private List<Elements> elements;

private List<OtherElements> otherElements;

public void init(int param) {
    this.param = param;
}

public List<Elements> getElements()  {

    if(this.elements == null) {
        //Init elements
        this.elements = otherService.getElements(param);
    }

    return this.elements;

}

public List<OtherElements> getOtherElements()  {

    if(this.otherElements == null) {
        //Init otherElements
        this.otherElements = otherService2.getOtherElements(param);
    }

    return this.otherElements;

}

public String getMainTextPres() {

    //Need to use lElements;
    List<Elements> elts = this.getElements();

    ....

    return myString;

}

public String getSecondTextPres() {

    //Need to use lElements;
    List<Elements> elts = this.getElements();
    //Also Need to use lElements;
    List<OtherElements> otherElts = this.getOtherElements();        

    ....

    return myString;

}
}
```

In my controller :

```
public class myController {
@Autowired MyService myService;

@RequestMapping...
public ModelAndView myFunction(int param) {
myService.init(param);

String mainTextPres = myService.getMainTextPres();

String secondTextPres = myService.getSecondTextPres();

}

@OtherRequestMapping...
public ModelAndView myFunction(int param) {
myService.init(param);

String secondTextPres = myService.getSecondTextPres();

}
}
```

Of course, I've simplified my example, because myService use lots of other elements, and i protect the initialization of his members attributes

This method has the advantage of doing lazy loading of the attributes only when I need them.
If somewhere in my project (in same or other controller) I only need the SecondTextPres, then calling "getSecondTextPres" will initialize both lists which is not the case in my example beacuse the first list has been initialized when "getMainTextPres" was called.

My question are :

- What do you think of this way of doing things ?
- May I have performance issues because I instantiate my service on each request ?

Thanks a lot !

Julien

Comment: And why would that be optimized with a request scoped bean. Each request has its own instance, there is nothing reused. If you really want to optimize fix your queries or use a cache. I suggest studying what Spring can do for you (and how you could cache results) instead of trying to hack something together yourself.

Comment: It's optimized because one the same request I use multiple times the same low level informations, and this way of doing things helps me to reuse datas I already have on the service layer.
I don't intend to optimize it on 2 differents requests

Comment: If you need an optimization like this in a single request, you might need to reconsider your flow. In a request only a single controller is consulted, everything else is a new request. Judging from your description it appears that you are trying to optimize something you haven't even measured or that really is a problem. Looks like you are trying to optimize things that not even might need optimizing. Remember: *premature optimization is the root of all evil*. Instead of introducing scopes, there are probably beter (and easier?) ways to improve things. But first measure, measure, measure.

Comment: Next to that if data is queried a lot, when using a decent database, that will optimize the fetching of data or optimizing the query.

Comment: You're right, I don't have measures. 
In fact, I know that I could reduce databases calls by doing that, this is why I want to do it, my database server is under heavy load, so if I can decrease the number of requests it's a good thing for me.
But I know my way of doing this isn't usual, this is why I ask my question today :)

Comment: You will only marginally reduce the load, because each request is still going to issue the queries at least once. As stated use a proper cache instead of hacking around with scopes. Next to that when using JPA you could integrate the cache with your JPA provider. There are better and standardized ways to do things, don't try to be smarter/reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Since yesterday I made some tests with Jmeter : 1000 pages, 10 times each. With simplecache : average response time : 290ms With my method and no cache : average response time : 271ms But the main thing is that the standard deviation is 202ms with cache and only 95ms with my method.

Comment: Try a better cache (like Google Caffeine or EhCache). Caches, for one, are designed for this, next to that they will even work in a distributed environment and if the same data is retrieved multiple times it will speed up. Also what have you tested, caching at the service level with `@Cacheable` or introducing 2nd level caching for your ORM provider, as those are different things.

Comment: I use @Cacheable at the service level because I don't have access to all third party functionnality.
I'm testing cache with ehcache this morning.

Comment: Here are the results with ehcache :
5 types of objects in cache. First time max 100 of each object in memory, second time max 1000 in mermory.
average response time : 284ms/270ms.
standard deviation : 111ms/96ms

Answer (score 0):

I think that your idea is not going to fly. I you call the same or different controller this is will be different request - in that case new bean will be created (elements and other elements are empty again).

Have you been thinking about caching? Spring has nice support where you can define cache expiration, etc

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact I want/need to have multiple instances because each request is different (dependaing on the params)

Comment: About cache : I've simplified my example beacause datas came from different sources. The main datas I use come from a database with millions of records, so I'm not sure to be able ta have a good cache (not enough memory)

Comment: "dependaing on the params" this is, probably, a wrong assumption. You just need a service which is able to provide different answers for different parameters and does not keep any internal state.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear to me what exactly you want to optimise instantiating Service in request scope? If you are bothered about memory foot print, you could easily measure it by JMX or VisualVM.

On the other hand, you could make all Service calls pure, i.e. depending on function parameters and (ofc) database state only and instantiate the Service with default scope as Singleton.

This decision will save you reasonable amount of resources as you will not instantiate possible large object graph on each call and will not require GC to clean the thing after Request is done.

The rule of thumb is to think why exactly you need the specific Class instantiated on every call and if it doesn't keep any state specific to call, make it Singleton.

Speaking about lazy loading, it always helps to think about worst case repeated like 100 times. Will it really save you something comparing to be loaded once and for the whole Container lifetime.

Comment: Thanks. I think I haven't been clear enough. Every day, the same "template" page is loaded millions times, but with different datas. Each time a page is loaded, I have about ten output informations I use to construct the informations returned to the client. My purpose when I made this service was to avoid fetching in database (or other sources) the same datas multiple times to construct the output informations.

Comment: In addition, I have other pages (and other controllers) that sometimes could use this service in order to get informations.
For example, I may have another controller which only needs to print the secondTextPres.

Comment: @JulienO  i'd say you need to split this service into two separate things: cache and actual service. 
The first one could be provided on many different levels (DB, HTTP, Service) and I can't suggest which one you should use without knowing your application very well. Please, dig into cache types and decide which one suits you best.
The second one should be made pure and provided as singleton.

Comment: I'll take a look at the cache possibilities.
I have to verify if it' could be applied (I use other services, with external datasources)

Comment: Since yesterday I made some tests with Jmeter :
1000 pages, 10 times each.

With simplecache : average response time : 290ms
With my method and no cache : average response time : 271ms

But the main thing is that the standard deviation is 202ms with cache and only 95ms with my method.

Comment: @JulienO We were talking about resource footprint, right? In your tests you were measuring the response speed and this is different a bit. But if you are going to check this very case, the run your test in parallel with 20-30 workers for 1000 different request each. This will provide you more or less true picture.
Next: such small difference may be explained by unused cache. Check the cache miss rates.

Comment: in fact my needs were : don't create overhead and make my server crash and getting pages loaded as fast as possible in order to be google friendly :)   Because as i said each page is loaded only 2-3 times a day, but we have millions of these pages (based on the same template) loaded by day.

I'm going to take a look to cache miss rates, thank you.

Comment: And still, google some discussion on pure function and stateless services. It could help you. Cheers!